# How to save symbol as readable in XML while writing it to a file?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, utf-8

I'm saving XML file in my Android app. While i'm writing it i'm using this method:

```
context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(source, "w")?.bufferedWriter()?.use { stream ->
    val xmlString = Xml.newSerializer().document {
        // some xml things
    }
    stream.write(xmlString)
}
```

and it's working file.

But when i'm saving cyryllic symbols and trying to open this file in reader app i see decimal HTML code. For example: `&#1055;` instead of `П`. I got advice that i need to save cyrillic symbols straight using it's UTF-8 value. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the official kotlin doc here https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/buffered-writer.html.

```kotlin
context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(source, "w")?.bufferedWriter(
    charset: Charset = Charsets.UTF_8)?.use { stream ->
    val xmlString = Xml.newSerializer().document {
        // some xml things
    }
    stream.write(xmlString)
}
```

Also, you need to open this file in reader app with the same encoding you specified.

Comment: This equals to my code. `bufferedWriter` using `UTF-8` as default value

Comment: @Danteee313 Did you use UTF-8 in the reader app? If so, you can try converting xmlString to bytes firstly, then write it to outputStream. Let me know if it works! `val byteArray = xmlString.toByteArray() contentResolver.openOutputStream(Uri.EMPTY, "w")?.write(byteArray) `

Comment: no it's not. i need to convert somehow symbols in utf-8 value

Comment: @Danteee313 According to https://www.codetable.net/decimal/1055, You have encoded `П` to UTF-8 correctly. So check if you have used the correct charset to open the file. I'm not sure which "reader app" you use, but for xml, you can add `<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" standalone = "no" ?>` to the head, this may help.

Comment: If @Danteee313 was opening file in the "reader app" with the wrong encoding, shouldn't they be seeing something like `?` or `�` (i.e., a replacement character)? The actual output they're seeing (`&#1055;`) looks more like `П` is being _escaped_ for some reason, not simply interpreted wrong by the "reader app". In other words, I think `&#1055;` is what's literally being written to the file.